# Magento 2 : Refuse to apply style

Tags: magento2, theme, css

I have this error :

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://www.portailclient-dev.com/pub/static/version1528816010/frontend/My/Theme/fr_FR/css/custom-m.css'
>   because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet
>   MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

In my `default_head_blocks.xml`, I have this (my theme extends luma) :

```
<head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
        <css src="css/custom-m.css"/>
        <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
    </head>
```

I do i fix this?

**EDIT**

The solution :

change `<css src="css/custom-m.css"/>` 
to `<css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom-m.css"/>`

Comment: Please post the solution as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

There could be 2 reasons

1. Your theme is not deployed for specific store view. You can try to deploy the theme for that specific store view like this

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR -f

2. Please check and insure that you have **.htaccess** file in your **pub/static/** folder. Also if you are working on Linux please check the file permission.